# How to get the First and Last Row Numbers of Four Rows to be Displayed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP page that displays all the rows in my MySQL table. The PHP page only shows the first four rows on the page http://mywebsite.ca/usedunits.php?page=1, and then creates a link to http://mywebsite.ca/usedunits.php?page=2. The link is the same page with the next four rows on it. For example, the first page would have rows one to four, then the second has five to eight. If there is 9 rows, the PHP creates another link that goes to http://mywebsite.ca/usedunits.php?page=3 and will display the ninth row there. My problem is that I am trying to display the links like this: [image]

So far, the `of 20 results` part shows up properly and so does the `pages 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > >>>` but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `1-4` part for each page.

Here is my full PHP page code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$dbhost = 'dam';
$dbuser = 'sbm';
$dbpass = 'Kis';
$dbname = 'ksbm';
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $connection )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$start_from = ($page-1) * 4; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `used_trailers` ORDER BY `orderid` ASC LIMIT $start_from,4";
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($connection, $sql); 
echo mysqli_error( $connection );
?>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Kelsey Nealon(Kelseynealon@gmail.com), Contract Web Developer" />
<meta name="description" content="GBM Trailer Service Ltd. Calgary-based, proudly serving the tanker and bulk goods transportation industry for over 25 years." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Tanker, Barrel, Parts, Betts, Camloc, Scully, Lubecore, Dixon, GBM, Flotech" />
<title>GBM Trailer Service Ltd. ::: Service</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/mobilemenu.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="responsiveused.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle2 -->
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").click(function () {
            $(".nav-button,.primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
    </script>

    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $('.Default').perfectScrollbar();
      });
    </script>

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45342007-3', 'gbmtrailer.ca');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#102540">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid">
    <div id="navcontain"></div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="mainnaviphone">
    <a href="../index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/gbmlogo.jpg" alt="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo" title="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo"/></a>
    <img src="images/newunitsbutton.png" alt="New Units Button" title="New Units Button" id="buto1">
  <img src="images/usedunitsbutton.png" alt="Used Units Button" title="Used Units Button" id="buto2">
  <a href="../index.html"><img src="images/homebutton.png" alt="home" title="Home" id="homebuto"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/previousbutton.png" alt="previous" title="Previous" id="prevbuto"/></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="images/nextbutton.png" alt="next" title="Next" id="nextbuto"/></a>
</div>

<div id="background2">
<div id="textcontrol">

<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
<div id='used1'>
<div id='rigtitle' class="contentHolder Default">
<? echo $row["title"]; ?>
</div>
<table class="infotabe1"><tr><td class="desctde">Description: </td><td rowspan="2" id="content_1" class="infotde contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["description"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Make: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["make"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Model: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["model"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Year: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["year"]; ?></td></tr></table>
<table class="infotabe"><tr><td class="desctd">Price: </td><td id="content_1" class="infotd contentHolder Default"><? echo $row["price"]; ?></td></tr></table>

<!-- Unit Picture -->
<img src='images/<? echo $row["photo"]; ?>' id='mainimage'>
<a href='#'><img src='images/picturesandspecsbutton.png' alt='Pictures and Specs' title='Pictures and Specs' id='picsandspecsbuto'></a>
</div>
<?php 
}; 
?>
</div>
<div id="description" class="resize">
  <p><u>Click</u> or call for more information or enquiries.</p>
</div>
<div id="bottomquote">
  Your Certified Tanker Trailer Specialist
</div>
<div id="bottomcontactinfo">
  <em>Phone <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-4032799717">403 279 9717</a> or <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-888-426-9717">1 888 426 9717</a> 9300 Endeavor Dr. SE, Calgary Alberta, T3S 0A1<br /><a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:info@gbmtrailer.ca">info@gbmtrailer.ca</a>
</div>

<img src="images/visamastercardlogos.gif" id="visamastercardlogos" alt="Visa and Mastercard Logo" title="Visa and Mastercard Logo">

<a href="#"><img id="mycart" src="images/mycart.gif" alt="My Cart" title="My Cart"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
<!--
var autoSizeText;
autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
};

autoSizeText(); // here is where we call the function.
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`orderid`) FROM `used_trailers`";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result); 
$total_records = $row[0]; 
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 4); 

$sqlef = 'SELECT * FROM `used_trailers`';
$rs_resultt = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlef); 
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($rs_resultt);

$record_start = $start_from + 1;
$record_end   = $record_start + 4;

// Remember to check against the max record
if ($record_end > $max_record) {
   $record_end = $max_record;
}

    echo "Showing ".$record_start." - ".$record_end." of ".$rowcount." results ";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='usedunits.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code:

```
$start_from = ($page-1) * 4; 

/*
Page      $start_from        What you want

  1       0                  Showing 1 - 4
  2       4                  Showing 5 - 8
  3       8                  Showing 9 - 12
 etc.
*/
```

If you notice the pattern for what you want, the record will start at `$start_from + 1`. The record will end at that value plus 4.

So, you can get what you want with this:

```
$record_start = $start_from + 1;
$record_end   = $record_start + 3;

// Remember to check against the max record
if ($record_end > $total_records) {
   $record_end = $total_records;
}
```

Comment: I am now getting `Showing 1 - of 6 results`. There should be a four after the `1 - `. I have updated my code in my question to what I currently have.

Comment: I updated my answer. Should use the variable `$total_records` instead of `$record_max`. I didn't see you have defined your variable for the total records.

Comment: It is now saying `1-5` on the first page. On the second page it says `5-6` which is correct because I have 6 rows total in the table.

Comment: Oopss.. Sorry for my math. The `$record_end` should be `$record_start` + 3, since you are showing 4 records. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The "1" would be:

```
$start_from + 1
```

The "4" would be:

```
Math.min($start_from + $rowcount, $total_records);
```

Math.min returns the smallest parameter passed to it.  In this case, we want to display start_from + row count until that number is bigger than the total records.

Comment: The math.min appears to output `math.6`. I'm assuming the six is because the total MySQL table rows is six.